# Asking About Expressing Oneself Better

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Is it off topic to ask how to learn to express oneself in a near fluent manner without visiting a predominantly German-speaking country? I do believe it's possible. Browsing this website daily would be one invaluable resource for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking for an idiomatic expression for writing or talking is one of the finer points we love to see discussed here on German Language.

So, yes, I strongly believe that any such question is on topic as long as it meets other criteria we had defined (e.g. one question - one answer, enough context provided, ideally some own research included, no list-question, not too subjective).

Comment: I was wondering if I could ask the question in general, but this still answers my question :). Thanks.